# Changing CSS of image depending on window size (responsive design)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got the responsive design to work so images change depending on the size of the window, however, I am unable to change the CSS of the individual classes. For example I would like to add a padding-top of 5% on class="logo-tablet-home" but on class="logo-desktop-home" I would like to add a black background and a padding-top of 10%. I had tried to just do it by using their individual classes in CSS but it's not having an affect on either.

```
    <picture>
      <source class="logo-mobile-home" srcset="Images/passive-logo-mobile.png" media="(max-width: 600px)">
      <source class="logo-tablet-home" srcset="Images/passive-logo-mobile2.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
      <source class="logo-desktop-home" srcset="Images/passive-logo-desktop.png" media="(min-width: 900px)">
      <img src="Images/header_images.png" alt="needed" style="width:auto;">
    </picture>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the element responsively, then you need to add CSS media queries to your CSS.

The `source` tag does not have any class attribute. You need to put that on your `img` tag like so:
`<img class="logo-mobile-home logo-tablet-home logo-desktop-home" src="Images/header_images.png" alt="needed" style="width:auto;">`

And your css with media queries should be:

```
/* For mobile phones: */
.logo-mobile-home {
  background:none;
  padding-top:0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .logo-tablet-home {
    background:none;
    padding-top:5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .logo-desktop-home {
    background:#000;
    padding-top:10%; 
  }
}
```